# When do I need to add annotation when I use Hilt as dependency injection?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm reading the article [Using Hilt in your Android app](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#7).

The Code A, Code B and Code C are from the [sample project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-hilt) in solution branch.

I'm confused when I should add the Hilt annotation.

1. In Code A, the parameter `database` of `fun provideLogDao` is injected, but the author doesn't add any annotation, but the parameter `appContext` of `fun provideDatabase` is marked with annotation `@ApplicationContext`, why ?
2. In Code B, the parameter `logDao` of `class LoggerLocalDataSource` is injected, but the author doesn't add any annotation, why?
3. In Code C, I'm told the following content, why isn't the parameter `activity` of `class AppNavigatorImpl` added any annotation? and you know `ApplicationContext` is predefined binding too, but the author add annotation `@ApplicationContex`t in `fun provideDatabase` in Code A.

*Because an AppNavigator instance is provided in the Activity container , FragmentActivity is already available as a predefined binding.*

**Code A**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "logging.db"
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideLogDao(database: AppDatabase): LogDao {
        return database.logDao()
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class LoggerLocalDataSource @Inject constructor(private val logDao: LogDao) : LoggerDataSource {
   ...
}
```

**Code C**

```
class AppNavigatorImpl @Inject constructor(private val activity: FragmentActivity) : AppNavigator {
   ...
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject lateinit var navigator: AppNavigator
    ...
}
```

Comment: Here update code about the hilt , good example 
https://github.com/jaswinderwadali/mvvm-compose-hilt-sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `@ApplicationContext` "tells" hilt to inject the application context, and not activity or service contexts. Also reminds us that injecting it will not cause memory leak.
2. `@Inject` is right there, at the left of the constructor. In DI terms, is called "Constructor Injection", which means that all of the parameters of the constructor will be injected by hilt without annotating those one by one.
3. Singleton component's object graph is not being garbage collected until your app is killed - injecting an activity there will cause memory leak.

Comment: Thanks! In Code A, the parameter `database` of `fun provideLogDao` is injected, but the author doesn't add any annotation, why?

Comment: Hi yo - no need, `@Provides` annotation causes all parameters to be injected using Hilt. If they cannot be injected (no provider for them or don't have `@Inject` in constructor), build will fail

Comment: In your case, `AppDatabase` have a provider